# metadata dependsOn not work in serverless framework template for GCP deployment manager

Tags: serverless-framework, google-deployment-manager

I want to create dependencies between resource services and find metadata:dependsOn is used in Deployment manager template.

However, when I applied the same syntax to serverless.yml, the resource that depends on the creation of others was not created. Checking the status of the services that it depends on, they were all created, and no errors showed up on deployment manager console about the resource itself and those it depends on.

is this a syntax issue? I do not find such example about resource dependency on the serverless gcp document.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation in creating explicit dependencies, it states that you cannot set a dependency on template files or composite types.[1] Attached are some documentation to better understand how you can achieve your goals. [2][3]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/create-explicit-dependencies

[2] https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/fundamentals#types

[3] https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types

Comment: I think my case is more like "You can create dependencies between base types that are part of your deployment, either in the configuration file, or in the templates that you use for the deployment" in the [1]. And the dependency I want is between topics and subscriptions, which are both base types.